# Converting byte array to integer - last value always converts to zero

Tags: java, arrays

When converting my byte array to an integer array for calculations, the integer array should be the same values as the byte array.  However, in my integer array, the last array value always outputs as zero.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arrCalc.length; intArray[i] = arrCalc[i++])
```

In this case, the arrCalc values are [97,98,99], and after the above code runs, intArray is showing [97,98,0] instead of [97,98,99].  Can anyone explain why this is and/or how to fix it?
*Note - I generally don't program in Java...if that matters at all...

Comment: This code works fine for me. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is your postfix. It is processed before you think it is.

Try breaking the code (besides, it is more Java-style compliant):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrCalc.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = arrCalc[i];
}
```

### [Oracle Site about Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

> The operators in the following table are listed according to
>   precedence order. The closer to the top of the table an operator
>   appears, the higher its precedence.

[image]

Comment: No. OP's postfix operation is fine (if unusual).

Comment: Worked like a charm with no errors - FINALLY.  Thank you!

Comment: The code you proposed is no different than OPs. It does the exact same thing.